# Create markdown files locally on netlify

Tags: node.js, web, netlify

I need to create md files locally on netlify. I using md files to store posts on my blog. Before I used Node Js server to create new md files, but now I want to deploy my page on Netlify, without external API.

Comment: And what doesnt work, what have you tried, what is your question, how can we help ?! Use the `fs` module in node for file manipulation.

Comment: I cant use fs module because netlify only contains final build files. Netlify download files from GIT repository and then use gatsby to build public files. So I can't create new files when the build is complete. There is my problem. Can I somehow use netlify and serverless functions to create the file and push it to my repository ?